# Uncaught Error: Not a valid 2D array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am creating a multidimensional array via an Ajax call to populate a Google Chart (Column). However the Array that is getting returned is causing this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not a valid 2D array.
```

This is the code that generates the array to send back:

```
$chartData = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($hourVal as $value) {

        if($i <= 9){
           $chartData[] = array(
               "0" . $i => (int) $value
            );
        } else {
            $chartData[] = array(
                $i => (int) $value
            );
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

This is the array when I console.log:

```
[
 [
  "Terms",
  "Visits"
 ],
 {
  00: 88
 },
 {
  01: 30
 },
 {
  02: 44
 },
 {
  03: 20
 }
]
```

EDIT: I add a row at the beginning of the array and also json_encode:

```
array_unshift($chartData, array("Terms","Visits"));
echo json_encode($chartData);
```

Any ideas what is going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: you gotta `json_decode`

Comment: Apologies, Yes I did. Forgot to add that. Will now.

Comment: Why are you doing `"0" . $i`?

Comment: Because I need the keys to be '01', '02', '03' etc..

Comment: @MarkP: Why?  Why do you need the keys like that?  That's the issue here.  If you make the keys `01`, `02`, etc, then `json_encode` creates an object (because those aren't numeric keys), thus making "Not a valid 2D array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, its because I was sending them through with a prefix of 0 and then it was making them the index of the array. Had to cut that bit out and send as string. Not desired but a fix :(

Answer (score 0):

That's not a 2D array.  it's an array of objects (and one array).  When you do `json_encode`, you only get an array if your PHP array is a numeric one (indexed starting at `0`).  Otherwise you get an object (since JavaScript/JSON doesn't have "associative arrays").

You need to make sure your array is numeric and indexed starting from `0`.

```
$chartData = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($hourVal as $value) {
    $chartData[] = array(
        $i => (int) $value
    );
    $i++;
}
```

I don't know why you were doing `"0" . $i`, but that's what was causing your problem.  That was creating an "associative array", which encodes as an object.